# Работа с временем в java

Tags: java

Прошу помощи, туплю к вечеру )))
Есть строка, представляющая собой время, например "17:38:55"
Нужно вычислить дельту с текущим временем, ее можно получить просто в мс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Парсим строку в дату посредством [`SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).
2. Из распарсенной даты получаем текущее время в [UTC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) посредством [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29). Помним, что мы не указали день, месяц и год, поэтому распарсенная дата будет представлять время 1 января 1970 года.
3. Получаем календарь с текущей датой и временем посредством [`Calendar.getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29).
4. Сбрасываем его дату в 1 января 1970 года посредством [`Calendar.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29).
5. Получаем из календаря время в UTC посредством [`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29).
6. Вычитаем из текущего времени время распарсенной даты.
7. ...
8. PROFIT!

Answer (score 1):

1) Чтобы вычислить разницу меж текущим и заданным временем надо одно из другого вычислить, приведя их к единому виду.

2) Для сего нам надо из заданной строки получить объект **Calendar** или **Date**, из коих, в свою очередь, получить **миллисекунды**.

3) Чтобы привести строку к объекту **Date** надо пояснить ему как **распарсить** строку.

4) Для парсинга дат есть классы **DateFormat** и **SimpleDateFormat**.

5) Делаем так:

```
String dateStr="17:38:55";

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss Z", new Locale("en"));
Date d = new Date();
try
{
        //преобразуем String в Date
    d = dateFormat .parse(dateStr);
        //получаем миллисекунды из даты
        long myMills=d.getTime();
        //получаем текущие миллисекунды
        long currentMils=System.currentTimeMillis();
        //теперь можно сравнивать
        long doIt=currentMils-myMills;
        System.out.print(doIt);
} catch (ParseException e)
{
     System.out.print("какая-то досадная ошибка!");
}
```

Comment: В вашем коде та же проблема, о которую споткнулся вчера и я.
myMills будет содержать количество миллисекунд, прошедших не с начала эпохи Юникс, а с начала суток!